# initwithCoder and encodewithCoder on iOS

Tags: ios, initwithcoder

I have tried to save the state of a `UIButton` by using `encodeWithCoder:`

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{  
  [coder encodeObject:self.button1 forKey:@"button1"];
}
```

My `initWithCoder:` looks like this:

```
-(void) initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder
{
  self.button1 = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"button1"];
}
```

With `button1` I save the state of the color, orientation, angle etc.  And I can restore it with `initwithCoder;` but when I tap the button it doesn't respond. The appearance has been restored but the `IBAction` is no longer called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're manually creating/restoring your buttons then you're taking away the automatic setup that InterfaceBuilder/NIB loading does for you.

You will need to add the target action to the button explicitly. *You also have some syntax errors in your example code.*

```
-(void) initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder
{
  self.button1 = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"button1"];
  [self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(yourIBActionMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```